# Upgrade old MT4 EA to new MT4 EA

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5, mql

I have an old EA for MT4. It has old functions and i want to upgrade it for new functions.

```
int init() {

//remaining code
return (0);

}

int deinit() {

//remaining code 
return (0);

}

int start() {

//remaining code 
return (0);
}
```

And if i want to upgrade to latest code, can i just change the name

```
int init() => void OnInit()


int deinit() => Void OnDeinit


int start() => void OnTick()
```

Like this :

```
void OnInit() {

//remaining code
return (0);

}

void OnDeinit(const int reason) {

//remaining code 
return (0);

}

void OnTick() {

//remaining code 
return (0);
}
```

Will this impact my EA functions and performance?